# Execute script when hard-disk's standby state changes (i.e. it spins up/down)

Tags: debian, hard-disk, hdparm

How can I execute a shell script when the standby state of a hard-disk (as reported by `hdparm -C /dev/sdx`) changes?

If possible, I would like to avoid polling `hdparm` for changes.

Comment: On what distribution?

Comment: @Gilles Debian.